# How to find active users in Ubuntu?

Tags: users

With help of the `who` command we can get active users,
I want only the first field
such as

```
user 1
user 2
user 3
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can get just the user names like so:

```
who | awk '{print $1}' | sort
```

Where `who` lists all logged in users, passes the output to `awk` which only prints the first section ("column") of text for every line, passes it to `sort` which sorts the output.

Comment: Or use `sort -u` instead of `sort | uniq`

Comment: Ok, did not know about that option.  (Or knew and forgot!)

Comment: You don't need to use awk: `who | cut --delimiter=' ' --field=1  | sort --unique` (the short version reads: `who|cut -d' ' -f1|sort -u`).

Comment: Unix always provides so many ways to skin a cat.  Its amazing any cats still have fur.

Comment: @PaddyLandau Why not put your answer in its own answer?